# Apache2, creating virtual hosts on one ip address

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I don't have the terminology to name this but essentially what I've been trying to do is run different web dev projects off of my ip address without any dedicated dns's. Ie. I can access different sites from 11.11.11.11/site1, 11.11.11.11/site2 and 11.11.11.11/site3.

Now I've always thought surely that's able to be done but I can't actually do it. I just get Error 404 everytime.

I've set up my .conf files in sites-available so the server name is '11.11.11.11/site#' and the DocumentRoot to /var/www/html/example.com/public_html for each host. Still no luck.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Here's an example of one of my .conf files that give me 404 Errors:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ###.###.###.###/example.html
        #the hashes represent my actual ip.

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        Alias /example.html /index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use alias :

```
Alias /site1 /home/site1/
Alias /site2 /home/site2/
Alias /site3 /home/site3/
# Don't add trailing slash at the end of the alias address ie. /site1/ is wrong .
```

[more inforamtion](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html)

based on your edit you may try it like this , please note the comments down :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 127.0.0.1
        #don't put any file name just dns name so you may use localhost 
        #or your domain.com or an IP.
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        Alias /site1 /var/www/html/folder/to/site1
        Alias /site2 /var/www/html/folder/to/site2

         #you will assign an alias folder name to real folder in your system 
         #so the first argument is /site1 and it can be anything you want 
         #you can make it /app and make it point to /path/to/site/2
         #You don't need to specify file names like you did in your example           
         #you just put the folder name and inside that folder you can access any file 
         #defult to index.html

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Good point Karam. But alas, I'm not getting any success. I tried what I thought you meant as you can see in my .conf file I just posted above. I'm still getting 404 Errors. I hope the .conf file makes it easy to understand the problem.